# Hide button if the tree traversal can't find the element

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is to make an if statement that checks if it can find the element and if it can't it hides a button with the class *.toggle*
The things is, there are multiple `.toggle` buttons on the page. They all open the closest `tr.product-info` **IF** available. Now I want to remove the button if the `tr.product-info` is not there. What's the best way to do this? My jQuery snippet so far:

```
if ($(".toggle").parents().eq(1).next(".product-info").text() === true) {
  $(".toggle").show();
}
else {
  $(".toggle").hide();
  console.log("test");
}
```

Part of the HTML

```html
<tr class="price-list">
  <td class="views-field views-field-field-product-table persist essential" data-th="">
    BNOR
  </td>            
  <td class="views-field views-field-field-price-table views-align-center persist essential" data-th="">
    € 218,00
  </td>
  <td class="views-field views-field-field-popup-table persist essential" data-th="">
    <a class="toggle" href="#" style="display: none;">Button</a>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class="product-info" style="display: none;">
  <td class="explanation">
    <p>Content to be displayed when clicking on Button</p>
  </td>            
</tr>
```

Comment: can you add how looks the HTML ?.... just the relevant part

Comment: DaniP, I updated my question with the HTML part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to loop across all `toggle` buttons, for that you can use `each()`:

> Searching if the next TR has the class .product-info:

**Check the Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').each(function(){
    if ($(this).closest('tr').next().hasClass("product-info")) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
      console.log("test");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="price-list">
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-product-table persist essential" data-th="">
      BNOR
    </td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-price-table views-align-center persist essential" data-th="">
      € 218,00
    </td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-popup-table persist essential" data-th="">
      <a class="toggle" href="#">Button</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product-info">
    <td class="explanation">
      <p>Content to be displayed when clicking on Button</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-list">
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-product-table persist essential" data-th="">
      BNOR
    </td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-price-table views-align-center persist essential" data-th="">
      € 218,00
    </td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-popup-table persist essential" data-th="">
      <a class="toggle" href="#">Button</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> Searching if there is no text inside the next TR

**Check the Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').each(function(){
    if ($(this).closest('tr').next().text().trim() !== "") {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
      console.log("test");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="price-list">
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-product-table persist essential" data-th="">
      BNOR
    </td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-price-table views-align-center persist essential" data-th="">
      € 218,00
    </td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-popup-table persist essential" data-th="">
      <a class="toggle" href="#">Button</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product-info">
    <td class="explanation">
      <p>Content to be displayed when clicking on Button</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-list">
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-product-table persist essential" data-th="">
      BNOR
    </td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-price-table views-align-center persist essential" data-th="">
      € 218,00
    </td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-popup-table persist essential" data-th="">
      <a class="toggle" href="#">Button</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product-info">
    <td class="explanation">
      <p></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer with another example. I'm new to jQuery and played a bit with it and it works great. Wasn't fully aware of the use of each(). Learned something today! :)

Comment: Glad to help U mate @nerdrocker

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the structure of your html page but if you only care that the `.product-info`'s text isn't blank, maybe you can loop through them an hide the buttons.

```
$('.product-info').each( function() {
  if ( $(this).text() ) {
    $(this).find('.toggle').show();
    return true
  };
  $(this).find('.toggle').hide();
});
```

or similarly to your code, you can loop through each toggle and see if it's parent `.production-info` exists and if it has text. It it doesn't exist, calling `#text` on an empty array, should return an empty string so it checks presence and text at the same time.

```
$('.toggle').each( function() {
  if ( $(this).parents('.product-info').text() ) {
    $(this).show()
    return true
  };
  $(this).hide();
});
```